# Clarifying notation of the Ker(f) in context of the first isomorphism theorem

Tags: functions, group-isomorphism

Hi I understand the first isomorphism theorem (in context of set theory) intuitively. It lets us turn a surjective image into a bijective one by partitioning them into classes based on the equivalence of the image value.

In my text book this bijection is defined as:

$$
\hat{f}: X/\text{Ker}(f) \rightarrow \operatorname{im}(f)
$$

Using my intuitive understanding I see it as an arrow from each partition class to an image value, giving our bijection.

What I do not understand is how my text book defines $\operatorname{Ker}(f)$:

$$
\operatorname{Ker}(f) = \{(x_1,x_2) \in X \times X \mid f(x_1) = f(x_2)\}
$$

When I try this on an example I see that it gives me a lot of pairs (including a subset defined by the identity function $\text{id}_A$. I do however not get how that would turn $X/\operatorname{Ker}(f)$ into my desired partition.

What am I missing?

(by the way I know that normally this is seen in the context of Group theory. While we do also see that in my text book later, this theorem is already defined as part of my chapter on set theory).

Comment: Recall that $X/\sim$, where $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$, is the set of equivalence classes; that is, the partition of $X$ induced by the equivalence relation $\sim$. Here, $\mathrm{Ker}(f)$ is the equivalence relation on $X$. What relation? Namely, that $x_1$ is related to $x_2$ if and only if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Now recall that an equivalence relation is also a subset of $X\times X$. So your book is telling you what the equivalence relation is as a set of pairs. Then $X/\mathrm{Ker}(f)$ is the partition of $X$ induced by this equivalence relation.

Comment: Thank you for replying @ArturoMagidin. Is there any specific reason why one would define it like this? While I do see how you can see equivalence based on what elements pair together, I do not understand why not define it as a partition directly, that would make it much more clear to me. Yet, I am sure the book was very carefully crafted, so there is probably a good reason why this is the best representation of $\text{Ker}(f)$ in this context.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. The very notation of the isomorphism theorem, $X/\mathrm{Ker}(f)$, assumes that you have an equivalence relation on $X$ and you are now defining a new function on the induced partition. The statement as given *requires* you to define it via an equivalence relation. You want to understand how the function defines an equivalence relation, and then you want to use that equivalence relation to define the partition and the quotient. (This is also what you will do later, in the algebraic context; semigroup, groups, etc)

Comment: Thank you @ArturoMagidin for your clarification, I understand now. I was not aware that this was the standard way of denoting how an equivalence relation was defined by a function. But now that I think about how a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ can be defined as a set of couples, it does make complete sense. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I think you mean **relations** defined via ordered pairs? The relation $R$ on $X$ defines a subset $S$ of $X\times X$ via $S=\{(a,b) \in X\times X\mid aRb\}$; and conversely, every subset $S\subseteq X\times X$ defines a relation $R$ via $aRb$ if and only if $(a,b)\in S$. Of course, functions are a special case of relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments made by @ArturoMagidin answered my question. I'll summarise it here.

The definition of the set $\text{Ker}(f)$ shows how the equivalence relationship $\sim$ defined on $A$ (for the image $f: A \rightarrow B$).

Once you know how $\sim$ is defined you can form a partition of $A$, identified in the text book an my question as $X/\text{Ker}(f)$. The bijection is as such induced on $f$ using $\sim$ as $\hat{f}: X/\text{Ker}(f) \rightarrow \text{im}(f)$, where $\text{im}(f) \subseteq B$.

The comments of @ArturoMagidin go in more detail.